# Removing Tweet with AJAX on button click

Tags: php, ajax, twitter

I am trying to delete a tweet with AJAX on button click. I am using [abraham's Twitter API](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth). When I click the button, I want to remove tweet and corresponding element. JavaScript code:

```
    $('.delete').click(function(){
        var el = this;
        var id = this.id;
        var splitid = id.split("_");

        // Delete id
        var deleteid = splitid[1];

        // AJAX Request
        $.ajax({
        url: 'deletetweet.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { id:deleteid },
        success: function(response){
            $(el).closest('.col-md-9').remove();
        }
        });
    });
```

With AJAX, I am sending data to "deletetweet.php" file that is in the same directory. PHP file:

```
require "api/config.php";
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
// Delete tweet
function deleteTweet($id) {
    $delete = $connection->post('statuses/destroy/'.$id, array());
    return $delete;
}

deleteTweet($id);
```

Lastly, in case if you need "config.php" file:

```
require "autoload.php";

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$c_key = 'C_KEY';
$c_secret = 'C_SECRET';
$a_token = 'A_TOKEN';
$a_token_secret = 'A_TOKEN_SECRET';

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($c_key, $c_secret, $a_token, $a_token_secret);
$user = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
```

Right now, removing the element part is working perfectly. However, removing tweet is not working. I actually don't know if my "deleteTweet" function is working properly and I don't know how to check if it is running or not.

**EDIT:** With a little more digging and debugging, I found the mistake. The problem was about global variabla "$connection". When I require "config" file in "deletetweet.php" file, I should also declare "$connection" variable as global variable. After that, it worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the api but did you forget a / before the ID and after destory  ?

```
function deleteTweet($id) {
    $delete = $connection->post('statuses/destroy'.$id, array());
    return $delete;
}
```

I guess the url is statuses/destory/id

Comment: That's correct. Here's the API documentation: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-destroy-id

Comment: Oh, sorry. My mistake. I changed it but it still does not work. I am confused about how "destroy" feature is working for Twitter API. When I run my function it does a request, I know that. But what should I do next? Should I return that statement "$connection->post..." or something else.

Comment: Is your request successful ? What http code is returned ? If it is successful you should also get a json body with quite a lot of information according to the api docs.

Also it looks like you have to add ".json" after the ID

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/destroy/:id.json

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the problem. It was about declaring "$connection" variable as global variable. After that everything worked pretty good.